# Seaside: receiver of 'contents' is nil

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I'm trying to just get started with Seaside in Pharo 3.0, but I've ran into an issue. I've been able to setup one of my classes successfully, but decided it was better to make a different class the `root`, so I relaunched Pharo to start fresh. However, on my other class I'm getting this when I navigate to the URL:

[image]

Does anyone know right off what would cause this? I inherit directly from WAComponent, I've setup the application in the Seaside config, and have implemented canBeRoot and renderContentOn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have `super initialize` in my initialize method. All is good now; feel free to disable/delete/howeveritworks this thread!  :)

Comment: There's a link at the bottom of this page that says 'answer own question'. Use that please.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the core developer of Pharo 3.0, I would like to mention that Pharo 3.0 is in early alpha mode. So pay attention because we are modifying many things. I would really suggest you to use Pharo 2.0 since many people are using it with Seaside.